# Remove folder with HTACCESS

Tags: .htaccess, apache

When users go to the following url:

```
http://mysite.com/folder/subfolder?a=blah&b=blah
```

I need to point them to content that is in the root folder while keeping the variables intact:

```
http://mysite.com/?a=blah&b=blah
```

Since http://mysite.com is a virtual host, this solution should also leave other base URLs alone.

I'd prefer not to do a full redirect because we use log tracking in our system and we need to have the headers return a 200 code for the logs (maybe this doesn't matter).

I know that this is a fairly straightforward question for someone who really understands .htaccess redirects. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean it should leave other URLs alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/?$ / [L,NC]
```